# Building MPFR and MPIR for UWP Visual Studio 2017

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, gmp, mpfr, mpir

Does anyone know if it is possible to build [MPFR](https://github.com/BrianGladman/mpfr) and [MPIR](https://github.com/BrianGladman/mpir) libraries using Visual Studio 2017 15.3 to be used in UWP app?

By the way, I can not build those libraries even not for UWP - too many errors :(

I am trying to follow ReadMe and Install instructions, but some files always missing or I get errors like

> MSB3721   The command ""C:\Program Files\yasm\"vsyasm.exe .......\mpn\x86w\umul_ppmm.asm" exited with code 1.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mpir-devel/XaHtUHeAVto/discussion ? In any case, it seems best to contact them directly on that forum.

Comment: It sounds like you need to install Windows' version of yasm which is vyasm if you haven't already done so. It is a compiler for asm. Then you either have to set system environment variables to its executable path and then use that within visual studio under build tools. Or you can just copy the exe file and place it within your project's directories under a bin folder. Either way you need to make sure visual studio knows where that folder is to find the executable. Also you have to set the custom build options to invoke it within the projects settings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install Windows' version of yasm which is vyasm if you haven't already done so. It is a compiler for asm. Then you either have to set system environment variables to its executable path and then use that within visual studio under build tools. Or you can just copy the exe file and place it within your project's directories under a bin folder. Either way you need to make sure visual studio knows where that folder is to find the executable. Also you have to set the custom build options to invoke it within the projects settings.